# How to insert data in transaction using entity-framewrok-4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to insert data in trasaction using entity-framewrok-4?

I have a order object and it has other collection that i need to inset in database in transaction.

```
cOrder->
 ->lstOrderItems
   -->lstDressing, lstTopping, lstspecialInstruction
 ->userDetails
 ->trasactionTblsdetails
```

Also opinion required:-
1) Is it good to maintain transaction at database level or entity framework level.
2) What should be coding style.

right now i am following it this way but as i can predict it would require a lot of code but want to know this is only the way it work or far better solution exist.

```
public static void SaveOrder()
    {
        using (EposWebOrderEntities Ctx = new EposWebOrderEntities())
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {

                // do something...
                Ctx.order.SaveChanges();
                // do something...
                //foreach to save the order items to databaswe
                Ctx.orderitems.SaveChanges();
                // do something...
                //foreach to save in dressing tbl
                Ctx.dressing.SaveChanges();
                //foreach to save in topping tbl
                Ctx.topping.SaveChanges();
                //foreach to save in dressing tbl
                Ctx.dressing.SaveChanges();
                //foreach to save in spinst tbl
                Ctx.dressing.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tables do not have a SaveChanges method. I'm also unclear on what you're asking. Any concrete problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way. Is sufficient in most scenarios.

```
public static void SaveOrder()
    {
        using (EposWebOrderEntities Ctx = new EposWebOrderEntities())
        {
             Ctx.Entry<Order>(order).State = EntityState.Added;
             Ctx.Entry<Dressing>(dressing).State = EntityState.Added;
             Ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843.aspx

> In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete >on the database the framework will wrap that operation in a transaction. This transaction lasts >only long enough to execute the operation and then completes. When you execute another such >operation a new transaction is started.

Comment: While true, this will not wrap anything else in a tran for example reads or multiple SaveChanges calls. Not very general.

Comment: for the collection in do not need to read each object with for-each and push to database..it will work..